# Simplifying a list of Directories

Tags: php, algorithm

Let's say if the user is able to select some directories to search. And he checkmarks the following directories below:

```
http://google.com/apple
http://google.com/apple/red
http://google.com/apple/green
http://google.com/apple/yellow
http://google.com/orange
http://google.com/orange/1
```

When getting ready to insert this data in lets say a database. Is there a way so I can simplify the list via PHP in order to show something like below:

```
http://google.com/apple
http://google.com/orange
```

Thanks
Cyrus

Comment: "Directories"? those are url paths...

Comment: Yes there is a way.  What have your tried? What is your criteria for "simplyfying" URL's down into a smaller set of URL's?

Comment: In the listed example:
http://google.com/apple
http://google.com/apple/red
http://google.com/apple/orange

to
http://google.com/apple

Comment: And Yes @Mike Brant, simplifying the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```php
sort( $paths );

$previous = $paths[0];
$simplified = array( $previous );

foreach ( $paths as $path ) {
    if ( $previous != substr( $path, 0, strlen( $previous ) ) ) {
        $simplified[] = $previous = $path;
    }
}
```

This code relies on the fact that a string sorts just before any extensions of itself.  Note that it doesn't treat slashes in any special way, and so it considers, say, `"quux/foo"` to be a valid prefix of `"quux/foobar"` (and this is not as easy to fix properly as I first thought it would be).  If you don't want that, make sure your paths have trailing slashes where appropriate.

Comment: Perfect! This is going to be a noob question but !== means not equal to just like !=. Or better word what does "$previous !== substr( $path, 0, strlen( $previous ) )" represent?

Comment: `!=` and `!==` are the same, except that the latter does [a stricter comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).  It probably doesn't matter here, I just used `!==` out of habit.  (Ps. I edited my answer, since the first versions had some potential problems.  Please see the new version, and the notes below it.)

Comment: So, to avoid that prefix issue. I should use paths like this: http://google.com/apple/ , http://google.com/ , http://apple.com/facebook/apple/. Just add an / in the end.